# 'function' object has no attribute 'load_data'

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c527140e2475> in <module>()
----> 1 (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fetch_lfw_people.load_data()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'load_data'
```

Comment: Apparently `fetch_lfw_people` is a function, not an object that has a `load_data` attribute. Show a [mcve] and say what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: It's best practice to write out all parts of the relevant source code to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to implement LFW datasets related to image recognition using VGG architecture.
I'm having this error in identifying data in the program code

Comment: @JST99 I want to implement LFW datasets related to image recognition using VGG architecture.
I'm having this error in identifying data in the program code

Comment: lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=53, resize=0.4)
IS THIS CODE use for classification picture in CNN????

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented above, it's considered best practice to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can identify where things might have gone wrong. This point notwithstanding, I think the description on the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_people.html) might be what you are looking for. One of the parameters of the `fetch_lfw_people` function is `return_X_y`:

> **return_X_y: boolean, default=False.**
>
> If True, returns (dataset.data, dataset.target) instead of a Bunch object.

Based on this description, you might want to try something like

```py
(X, y) = fetch_lfw_people(return_X_y=True)
```

Of course, you can specify any other parameters according to your needs.

Comment: in LFW dataset we have RGB? Xnew_train.shape .... (873, 1, 224, 224) why here is 1???

Comment: lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=53, resize=0.4) IS THIS CODE use for classification picture in CNN????

Comment: Missed your earlier comment. You can make the function return RGB images by toggling the `color` parameter (i.e. `fetch_lfw_people(color=True, return_X_y=True)`). I'm not sure if I understand your second question. Yes, you can use the returned images for a classification task using a CNN.